# Continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

Show that if a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous where $\mathbb{R}$ is in the cofinite topology then the mapping is constant or finite to one.

I have seen other answers to this where someone shows either the contrapositive or proof by contradiction, but why can't I do this?:

Let $y$ be an element of the codomain. Since $f$ is continuous and $\{y\}$ is closed $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is closed in the domain. Since the only closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$ with the finite complement topology are $\mathbb{R}$ itself and finite sets, one of the cases must occur:

$f^{-1}(\{y\})=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=y$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is constant.

Or for each $y \in \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(\{y\})=A$ for some finite set $A$.

If the first case holds the function is constant. If the next case holds it is finite to one.

Comment: I think this is basically fine. As written there's a little inconsistency with the quantification of $y$ (you've proved that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is either finite or $\Bbb R$ for any given $y$, but that's not exactly the same as showing that $f$ itself is constant or finite-to-one—although the gap is small and easily addressed). But perhaps the reason others use less direct proofs is that they're more comfortable talking about open sets in the cofinite topology than closed sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either there is a $y$ such that $f^{-1}[\{y\}]=\Bbb R$ and $f$ is constant with value $f$, or no such $y$ exists and then **all** $f^{-1}[[\{y\}]$ are finite (including possibly empty), as these options are the only possibilities for closed sets. The latter case says $f$ is finite-to-one by definition.